# How to find the maximum minimum point of a function in pyhon?

Tags: python, scipy, root, minimize

I need to find the maximum minimum point of a function.

There are 2 matrices `M_A`, and `M_B`, where `M_A < M_B` and `I > M_B` (element-wise comparison), where `I` is the matrix of all ones.

I need to find the maximum `x` value (between 0 and 1) such that:

`x*M_A+(1-x)*I >= M_B` (element-wise comparison)

To do this I am trying to find the root of the following of the following expression `x*M_A+(1-x)*I - M_B`. To do this, I define a scalar function by taking the sum of all negative entries of the above expression (`x*M_A+(1-x)*I - M_B`). The objective is to find the `x` value such that `my_f(x)=0`. However, there are infinite `x`s that satisfy this condition, for example `my_f(0)=0`. I would like to get the maximum `x`.

```py
def my_f(x):
    matrix_comb = x*M_A + (1-x)*np.ones((n, n))
    matrix_diff = matrix_comb - M_B
    summ = 0
    for i in range(0, len(matrix_diff)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix_diff)):
            if matrix_diff[i,j] <= 0:
                summ = summ + matrix_diff[i,j]
    return -summ

my_f(scipy.optimize.fminbound(my_f, 0, 1))
```

The code returns 0.85. However, there are other greater `x` values satisfying the conditions.

Comment: When you say that `M_A < M_B`, are you referring to the element-wise comparison? Also, what is `M_V`? Why are you summing the negative values?

Comment: What does `x*M_A+(1-x)*I >= M_V` mean that you are performing the sum of the entries? I'm assuming `M_V` is a matrix, in which case I don't know what the comparison is here and what it means for this to be satisfied.

Comment: And if you're trying to satisfy `my_f(x)=0`, that is a root-finding problem, not a minimization problem. You seem to want to be doing both a maximization (to find the largest `x`) and a root-finding problem (where `x` is the root).

Comment: By ```M_A < M_B``` I do mean element-wise comparison. I want the maximum ```x``` satisfying the inequality ```x*M_A+(1-x)*I >= M_V``` (element-wise comparison). Then, I look for the maximum ```x``` satisfying the equality ```x*M_A+(1-x)*I = M_V```. Therefore, yes it's both maximization and root-finding problem

Comment: I can't help but notice that you never use M_B? Do you mean M_B every time you write M_V?

Comment: If you write "where I is the matrix of all ones" you are going to confuse a lot of people. I is usually an identity matrix with 1 on the DIAGONAL and 0 everywhere else. If MA>=MB and all the entries are at least 1 then an infinity of values of x would fit the bill. Your question doesn't make much sense, to be honest - please give the ORIGINAL problem, not a rendering that is likely to lead to an XY-problem.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question literally; that is, you really are looking for maximum `x` subject to your inequality; I ignore everything after *To do this I am...*. as root-finding does not help with this goal.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy


rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
m = 13
n = 7
M_A = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(m, n))
M_B = rand.uniform(low=M_A, high=1, size=(m, n))

'''
Maximize x s.t.
0 <= x <= 1
x*M_A + (1-x)*ones >= M_B
x(MA - 1) >= MB - 1
'''

result = scipy.optimize.milp(
    c=-1,           # maximize
    integrality=0,  # continuous
    bounds=scipy.optimize.Bounds(lb=0, ub=1),
    constraints=scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint(
        A=M_A.reshape((m*n, 1)) - 1,
        lb=M_B.ravel() - 1,
    )
)
assert result.success, result.message

print('x =', result.x)
```